# Implementing a type class using a GADT

Tags: haskell, gadt

I have written the following linear algebra vector in Haskell

```
data Natural where
    Zero :: Natural
    Succ :: Natural -> Natural

data Vector n e where
    Nil :: Vector Zero e
    (:|) :: (Show e, Num e) => e -> Vector n e -> Vector (Succ n) e
infixr :|

instance Foldable -- ... Vector ..., but how do I implement this?
```

When I try to implement `Foldable`, I run into the problem that `Zero` and `Succ` have different definitions (ie. * and * -> *).

Is there an obvious solution to this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just

```
instance Foldable (Vector n) where
  fold Nil       = mempty
  fold (a :| as) = a <> fold as
```

I would not recommend adding constraints to the `e` type, though.

Comment: So I can use the `Monoid` functions without `Vector` implementing them? EDIT: Also, could you elaborate on why adding the constraints in the `e` type is a bad idea, if it's not too much of a derail?

Comment: Note that I'm calling the monoid functions only on the values contained in the Vector. And the constraints are bad because they'll appear in every signature you use the Vector in. Typically it's found to be better to state typeclass constraints only in the functions that need them.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to mention `Zero` or `Succ` in the class instance, that is the entire point of a GADT: pattern matching on the constructor gives you type information:

```
instance F.Foldable (Vector v) where
  foldr _ zero Nil = zero
  foldr f zero (e0 :| v) = f e0 $ F.foldr f zero v
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm still getting used to using GADTs! :D